# Laravel eloquent - one to one relation with different table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables,

```
1. user (id, name)
2. state (id, stateName, code)
3. user_relations(id, user_id, state_id)
```

3 models,

```
1. User
2. State 
3. UserRelation
```

> By logic, `User` has one `UserRelation` and `UserRelation` has one `State`

I can get user state by

```
User::first()->relation->state
```

**What I want** is call this by `User::with('state')->first()`.

Comment: User has one relation, one relation has one state, why do you still create the relation table, you can just add user_id column to state table.

Comment: Does user has one or many state(s) ?

Comment: the current structure is this way. If i modify this, then i have to modify the hole system. so I cant.
Other reason is, for example user table has around 20 columns and it has around 15 relations.

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI sir, nope. user has only one state in our system logic.

Comment: So why use intermediate table like `user_relations(id, user_id, state_id)` ? I think it's useless.

Comment: according to your comment, I think one state has many users.

Comment: sir, I cannot modify the database structure. cause I have no permission.

Comment: @TsaiKoga sir, thats true, But this is non of my concert. cause I want, `user -> state`

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep the current db schema like it is, you may use [Laravel accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

> Accessors and mutators allow you to format Eloquent attribute values
>   when you retrieve or set them on model instances.

class User

```
public function getStateAttribute($value) {
   return $this->relation->state;
}
```

Usage

```
User::findOrFail($id)->state;
```

**Edit**

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //...

    public function state() {
        return $this->relation()->with('state');
    }


    public function relation() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserRelation', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

UserRelation Model

```
class UserRelation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_relations';


    public function state() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\State'); // must be belongsTo instead of hasOne
    }

}
```

State Model

```
class State extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'states';
}
```

Controller

```
App\User::with('state')->find(1);

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "email_verified_at": "2020-02-13 00:00:00",
  "created_at": "2020-02-20 00:00:00",
  "updated_at": null,
  "state": {
    "id": 2,
    "state_id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "state": {
      "id": 2,
      "stateName": "state 2",
      "code": "code 2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works.  But I cannot call it by with.
`User::with('state')->findOrFail($id);`

Comment: This answer was in response to "What I want is call this by User::first()->state."

Comment: pardon me, I need `User::with('state')->first()` this way, so that I can pass it to json response. The question is already updated.

Comment: sir, I appreciate your approch. thats good. But I need output like 
`{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "state": {
            "id": 2,
            "stateName": "state 2",
            "code": "code 2"
        }
    }`  With a single eloquent query.

Comment: I mean, I can loop on user list and can change `state.state` to `state`.
But what I need, do it by query.

Answer (score 0):

If user can only have one state,

add a  `state_id` in the user table and get rid of the third table `user_relations`

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function state()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\State');
    }
}

class State extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

In this way, you can

```
$state = User::find(1)->state;
$user = State::find(1)->user;
```

Comment: sir, I cannot modify the database structure. cause I have no permission.

Comment: In that case, this answer will not work for you. Some other user with similar problem might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

> First way:

You have to define state_id in users table for one to one relation.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function state()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\State');
    }
}
```

Or if you need same database structure, then

> Second Way:

Basically it's **Many to Many relations between User and State**.

So better way is to define many to many relation function in Models of User and State considering UserRelation a **middle(pivot) table.**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function states()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\State', 'user_relations');
    }
}

class State extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_relations');
    }
}
```

and then to access states of user, you can call:

```
$user->states->first();
```

It's ok that you need one to one relation, you can call first() method to fetch first record od state.

Simillery to access user of state

```
$state->users->first();
```

And if you need to access user_relations (one to one) only, you have to define methods in both user and state model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function user_relation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserRelation');
    }
}

class State extends Model
{
    public function user_relation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserRelation');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since user and state are many to many, you can user belongsToMany function inside User model.

```
public function states(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(State::class, 'user_relations', 'user_id', 'state_id');
}
```

You can get [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) by retrieving both models related to the user like:

```
$user = User::with('states')->first();
```

And now to retrieve states, you can loop through the states like:

```
foreach($user->states as $state){
    //Retrieved state model variable
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing `one-to-one` relationship you won't need a pivot table, in your case the `user_relations` table. Pivot tables are used to express `many-to-many` relations.

And for the solution you want. You will have to store the user_id in the `state` table.
so your state table should look like the following:

`state (id, user_id, stateName, code)`

**Relations should be like:**

User model:

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\State');
}
```

State model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```